# Importing big matrices from a text file efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, parsing, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to import big matrices (around 5000x5000) from txt files with python, which will be later subjected to simple algebraic operations via `scipy.linalg.`

The data has the following form below, 16x16 matrix as an example. How can I read and clean-up the data as np arrays from txt files in an efficient manner?

```
-----------------
SOC MATRIX (A.U.)
-----------------

Real part:
                  0          1          2          3          4          5
      0    -1382.309942   0.000000   0.000000   0.009193   0.000000   0.000000
      1       0.000000-1382.309942  -0.009193  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      2       0.000000  -0.009193-1382.309942   0.000000   0.000000   0.011260
      3       0.009193  -0.000000   0.000000-1382.309942  -0.011260  -0.000000
      4       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.011260-1382.309942   0.000000
      5       0.000000   0.000000   0.011260  -0.000000   0.000000-1382.309942
      6       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.011260
      7       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.011260  -0.000000
      8       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      9       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
     10      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
     11      -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
     12       0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
     13       0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
     14       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
     15       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
                  6          7          8          9         10         11
      0       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      1       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
      2       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      3       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      4       0.000000   0.011260   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      5      -0.011260  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
      6    -1382.309942  -0.000000   0.000000   0.009193   0.000000   0.000000
      7      -0.000000-1382.309942  -0.009193  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      8       0.000000  -0.009193-1382.309942  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      9       0.009193  -0.000000  -0.000000-1382.309942   0.000000   0.000000
     10       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000-1382.216985   0.000000
     11       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000-1382.216985
     12      -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000523
     13      -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000523   0.000000
     14      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
     15      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
                 12         13         14         15
      0       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      1       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      2      -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      3      -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
      4      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      5      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
      6      -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      7      -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      8       0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000
      9       0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000
     10       0.000000  -0.000523   0.000000   0.000000
     11       0.000523   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
     12    -1382.216985   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000523
     13       0.000000-1382.216985   0.000523   0.000000
     14       0.000000   0.000523-1382.216985  -0.000000
     15      -0.000523   0.000000  -0.000000-1382.216985
```

Comment: Check out [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html?highlight=loadtxt#numpy.loadtxt) with the `skiprows` parameter.

Comment: However, the fact that the file restarts from entry 0 in order to list higher columns does make things difficult, since usually all columns pertaining to an entry are listed on the same line.

Comment: Ain't that a 16x16 matrix?

Comment: Yes, the example is 16x16, I've fixed that in the original post, thanks

Comment: With a layout like that there isn't a simple out-of-the-box solution, much less an "efficient" one.  One way or other, you have read and parse each line.  `np.loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt`) can be used to load uniform blocks of the text, though they aren't any  more efficient than hand coded reads.